# How to handle error when we use Redux-Saga all effect in a loop?

Tags: redux, error-handling, redux-saga

I have a list of items that need to be downloaded. I have already START_DOWNLOAD action. So, all I need to do call the action in a loop. We are using redux-saga and the code,

```
yield all([items.map(item => put(initDownload(item)))]);
```

is working well unless if one of the download is failed. Failing one item fails the entire collection.

How can I start parallel actions in a loop that does not affect each other?